# how to use styles defined in ResourceDictionary

Tags: wpf, xaml, windows-8.1, resourcedictionary

I have several common styles and I want to share them in several pages of my Windows 8.1 application.

I know that I can achieve with [merge dictionaries option](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa350178.aspx), but I have no idea how to use styles defined in dictionary.

I tried this:

```
<Page.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary x:Key="lol">
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="Themes/Generic.xaml" />
        <ResourceDictionary>
            <Style x:Key="TextViewAllStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            </Style>
        </ResourceDictionary>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    <Style x:Key="TextViewAllStyle2" TargetType="TextBlock">
    </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
<Style x:Key="TextViewAllStyle3" TargetType="TextBlock">
</Style>
</Page.Resources>
```

But my Visual Studio sees only the third one...

```
<TextBlock Style="{StaticResource ResourceKey=TextViewAllStyle3}"/>
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

add the following tag to your App.Xaml:

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            -- reference your dictionaries here --
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Then for `-- reference your dictionaries here --` part: each dictionary can be added by its full path:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="pack://application:,,,/MySolution.MyProject;component/Theme/Generic.xaml"/>
```

if in the same project by its relative path:

```
<ResourceDictionary Source="Themes\Generic.xaml"/>
```

or defined inline:

```
<Style x:Key="TextViewAllStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
</Style>
```

Comment: Its giving me an error that the resources-property may only be set one time.

Comment: you have probably defined multiple dictionaries or other resources within the resources tag. if you move them to MergedDictionaries it should be fine. see this link http://stackoverflow.com/a/3425956/366064

Comment: Thanks for replying. I've found my problem. Away form the defined dictionary, I still hard some custom styles inside my app.xaml. I just had to surround them with `<ResourceDictionary>` inside the merde-block. Everything is fine :).