# WPF Styling : Resource not found; ResourceKey

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, resources, wpf-style

I have some styles and templates in `App.Xaml` so I can acces them thru multiple `UserControls`.

EDIT : This is within the app.Xaml:

One of the Styles are :

```
<Application x:Class="BaseRefence.generatingAnnotation.App"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:BaseRefence.generatingAnnotation"
             xmlns:Themes="clr-namespace:Microsoft.Windows.Themes;assembly=PresentationFramework.Aero2"
             StartupUri="MainWindow.xaml">
<Application.Resources>
<Style x:Key="ComboBoxStyleRounded" TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
   <Setter Property="Template">
      <Setter.Value>
         <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
            <Grid>
               <Border CornerRadius="25"
                       BorderThickness="1,1,2,2">
               </Border>
            </Grid>
         </ControlTemplate>
      </Setter.Value>
   </Setter>
   <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{StaticResource FocusVisual}"/>
   <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ComboBox.Static.Background}"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderBrush" Value="#42536b"/>
   <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Black"/>
   <Setter Property="BorderThickness" Value="1,1,2,2"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.VerticalScrollBarVisibility" Value="Auto"/>
   <Setter Property="Padding" Value="6,3,5,3"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll" Value="true"/>
   <Setter Property="ScrollViewer.PanningMode" Value="Both"/>
   <Setter Property="Stylus.IsFlicksEnabled" Value="False"/>
   <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}"/>
   <Style.Triggers>
      <Trigger Property="IsEditable" Value="true">
         <Setter Property="IsTabStop" Value="false"/>
         <Setter Property="Padding" Value="2"/>
         <Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxEditableTemplate}"/>
      </Trigger>
   </Style.Triggers>
</Style>
</Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

And in de UserControl.Xaml I have:

```
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding ViewFamilyTypesInProject}"                                                              
          SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedViewFamilyType, Mode=TwoWay}"
          Grid.Row="1"
          Grid.Column="1"
          Margin="10 5"
          MaxHeight="40"
          Style="{DynamicResource ComboBoxStyleRounded}">
```

Within the designer everything works great, it shows correctly and all.
However, whenever I build and run my code, it gives the message and it does not override the style but keeps the default style.

```
System.Windows.ResourceDictionary Warning: 9 : Resource not found; ResourceKey='ComboBoxStyleRounded'
```

Comment: Can you access the other templates / styles ?

Comment: why dynamic? did you try StaticResource?

Comment: None of the created Styles are accessible. I just did the edit template -> make a copy. and moved that to Application.resources instead of UserControl.resources

Comment: Yes I tried Static, but then the total app crashes when I try to load the usercontrol

Comment: Are the UserControl and App.xaml in the same project? Can you add the App.xaml? (with just the ComboBox style)

Comment: Yes they are in the same project. within the same namespace. The top part of the question is within the App.Xaml.

Comment: Try to wrap the styles in a ResourceDictionary.

`<Application x:Class="Foo.Bar"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
  <Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
         <Style/>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>`
...

Comment: This did not work, do I need to adress the style bind differently when I Wrap it in a ResourceDictionary? the Odd thing is that within my designer it works Fine

Comment: Move the ComboBox style to the bottom of the App.XAML. It’s a known “bug”.

Comment: That didn't work, beside, it's with every style I made. I just created a new sample project, within that it works just fine, wich makes it even more odd for me

Comment: use a static resource and try to put the style in a dictionary like in this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22114430/366064

also you might want to rename the style, maybe it's defined elsewhere

Comment: If everything should work then I would suggest deleting `obj` folder in your solution. Then clean project and then build it. See if that helps, looks like there might be some leftover artefacts from precious builds.

Answer (score 2):

My experience: I frequently have same issues (using VS 16.6.2, .NET Core 3.1 and WPF).

Simply close Visual Studio and restart it: 98% of the times error disappears (will reappear sometime in the future).

Answer (score 0):

You have an invalid `Style`. It may compile, as the XAML is syntactically correct, but the semantics of the markup are wrong. Since you are referencing the `Style` using `DynamicResource` the error occurs at runtime. But I wonder why don't get a XAML Designer error.

You are setting the `ComboBox.Template` property twice. Moreover and most important, the first `ControlTemplate` at the top of the `Style` is targeting the wrong type `TextBox`:

```
<ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TextBox}">
  <Grid>
    <Border CornerRadius="25"
            BorderThickness="1,1,2,2">
    </Border>
  </Grid>
</ControlTemplate>
```

The type must be of course `<ControlTemplate TargetType="ComboBox">`.

Since you are referencing a `ControlTemplate` resource later

```
<Setter Property="Template" Value="{StaticResource ComboBoxTemplate}" />
```

I think you want to remove the first `ControlTemplate`. If you want to change the appearance of the `TextBox`, you would need to override the complete `ControlTemplate` of the `ComboBox`.
You may should run `Clean Solution` and `Rebuild Solution`.